# Facebook Application Redirect Loop after authentication

Tags: facebook, facebook-c#-sdk

I've encountered this problem while using the facebook c# sdk v4.2.1:

After allowing the app, a user using a IE browser without flash being installed will go on a infinite redirect authentication loop.

At first i thought it was a cookie problem , until i tested on another computer and realised that both of the computers had no flash installed.

Has anyone encountered this problem before? I know for sure i've encountered alot of problems that using the official facebook javascript sdk to authenticate users on IE without flash.

I would appreciate if anyone found a solution to this problem can answer this question.

Answer (score 0):

Flash shouldn't be the problem. Did you install the Facebook handler in your web.config?

Also it sounds like you aren't being properly authenticated. You might want to sniff with something like Fiddler and see what is happening.

Comment: However, installing flash for IE fixed the problem on two computers in our office. I will try to sniff anything i could out of it

Comment: Flash definitely makes a difference in some scenarios with how the Facebook Javascript client library works, and that library is integral to most login/auth implementations for FB apps.  I have seen this problem with IE7 on Vista with no flash for sure (can repro at will and have an open bug in Facebook's bugzilla, bug ID 15148)

Answer (score 0):

Would you please edit you Facebook settings on Facebook i had the same problem before and i edit the settings on the advanced tap and it works :)

https://www.facebook.com/developers/apps.php?app_id=app_id

hope that works .

Comment: Actually it was one year since i made this app ,i will look for answer then return back to you

Answer (score 0):

I just had this problem when reviving an older facebook app. I fixed it by enabling "signed_request for Canvas" in the Advanced settings tab on for the app on facebook.